# Create grid lines and allow user to on/off grid line view

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, grid

I would like to create a grid line approach in my app and allow the user to switch on/off the grid view. It doesn't need to have any sort of touch detection or a logic associated to it. Just grid lines for the user to see and turn them on/off. The obvious solution for this would be to add an image of grid to my view and display it whenever required using an imageview. But that is an option that I cannot take. I have to do it programmatically. Thanks for your time. An [image](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_clEfRZeg1Fk/SJxDvEH3N8I/AAAAAAAAAXo/sPPAn3MYJ9E/s400/step1.jpg) of what I am planning to implement. Any ideas ? Core graphics or many uiviews ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using this:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"]];
```

Answer (score 3):

I have used this for **Swift3**

```
class GridView: UIView {

    var numberOfColumns: Int = 2
    var numberOfRows: Int = 2
    var lineWidth: CGFloat = 1.0
    var lineColor: UIColor = UIColor.white

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {

            context.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
            context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)

            let columnWidth = Int(rect.width) / (numberOfColumns + 1)
            for i in 1...numberOfColumns {
                var startPoint = CGPoint.zero
                var endPoint = CGPoint.zero
                startPoint.x = CGFloat(columnWidth * i)
                startPoint.y = 0.0
                endPoint.x = startPoint.x
                endPoint.y = frame.size.height
                context.move(to: CGPoint(x: startPoint.x, y: startPoint.y))
                context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: endPoint.x, y: endPoint.y))
                context.strokePath()
            }

            let rowHeight = Int(rect.height) / (numberOfRows + 1)
            for j in 1...numberOfRows {
                var startPoint = CGPoint.zero
                var endPoint = CGPoint.zero
                startPoint.x = 0.0
                startPoint.y = CGFloat(rowHeight * j)
                endPoint.x = frame.size.width
                endPoint.y = startPoint.y
                context.move(to: CGPoint(x: startPoint.x, y: startPoint.y))
                context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: endPoint.x, y: endPoint.y))
                context.strokePath()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And set its background colour as `clear`.

The code is also present [here](https://gist.github.com/NikhilManapure/bb42028e296a793c76083773ca18e532)

Answer (score 1):

Subclass a UIView and create separate 2 loops in there. One for vertical lines and one for horizontal lines.
In the vertical lines loop, create UIView’s 1px wide and 768px high. In horizontal one, create them 1px high and 1024px wide.

To hide and show it, just switch the subclassed view’s hidden property to either YES or NO.

You can possibly do without the subclassing as well, just use a standard UIView.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, that seems an easy way. Look at the update. For this, I will have to create atleast 40 uiviews with different border widths and implement a logic to position them ?

Comment: For the dotted lines I’d probably use an image, but yes, it seems that’s what you’ll have to do. As those are very simple UIView’s, you shouldn’t have any problems with this solution.

Comment: Okay but the problem is I cant use images. I will need an alternate solution.

Comment: Then I guess you’ll have to dig into Core Graphics. I’m not really familiar with that myself unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, if I get something in core graphics for this I will follow that or else will do what you suggested. Thanks.